# How to send SMS from Twilio API using proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, sms, twilio

I'm new to Twilio and I am trying to create a sample code for sending SMS to a number. I already created account on Twilio and written a program which is working good on local. but now going further that program is not able to send SMS from Prod server. what i can to know that we can communicate to external uri through proxy. so i implemented proxy in my code. below is the property which i set for proxy information in TwilioRestClient.

```
 var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
 twilio.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://ProxyAddress", 8080);
```

But this code is not working after adding proxy to it. can any one help me in this. is this the right way of doing that?

Comment: Here is a useful link for your solution https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181868-How-can-I-troubleshoot-if-an-SMS-message-sent-from-Twilio-doesn-t-arrive-

Comment: Show us some code, the one that works on local. Are you using, PHP, C#, Python, etc.... Are you using any environment variables that are not set on production? Do you get an error message? We can't read your mind.

Comment: This is the sample code i am using to execute on local and Prod server. it is written in c#.        
                string AccountSid = "accountId";
                string AuthToken = "token";
                var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
                twilio.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxyaddress", 8080);
                var message = twilio.SendMessage("+1fromNumber", "+1toNumber", "Sample Message Test");